# Pandas: importing Date and 12 hour Time together

Tags: python, pandas, text

I have the following txt file:

```
            Temp    Hi  Low Out Dew Wind    Wind    Wind    Hi  Hi  Wind    Heat    THW THSW            Rain    Solar   Solar   Hi Solar    UV  UV  Hi  Heat    Cool    In  In  In  In  In  In Air      Wind    Wind    ISS     Arc.
Date    Time    Out Temp    Temp    Hum Pt. Speed   Dir Run Speed   Dir Chill   Index   Index   Index   Bar     Rain    Rate    Rad.    Energy  Rad.    Index   Dose    UV  D-D     D-D     Temp    Hum Dew Heat    EMC Density ET  Samp    Tx  Recept  Int.
01/01/16    12:30 a 13.8    13.8    13.6    88  11.9    0.0 --- 0.00    0.0 --- 13.8    13.8    13.8    12.4    1012.3  0.00    0.0 0   0.00    0   0.0 0.00    0.0 0.094   0.000   21.5    50  10.6    20.7    9.25    1.1823  0.00    702 1   100.0   30
01/01/16    1:00 a  13.6    13.8    13.2    88  11.7    0.0 --- 0.00    0.0 --- 13.6    13.6    13.6    12.2    1012.2  0.00    0.0 0   0.00    0   0.0 0.00    0.0 0.098   0.000   21.5    50  10.6    20.7    9.25    1.1823  0.00    702 1   100.0   30
01/01/16    1:30 a  14.5    14.5    13.6    81  11.3    0.0 --- 0.00    0.0 --- 14.5    14.4    14.4    12.9    1012.2  0.00    0.0 0   0.00    0   0.0 0.00    0.0 0.080   0.000   21.5    50  10.6    20.7    9.25    1.1822  0.00    703 1   100.0   30
01/01/16    2:00 a  15.2    15.2    14.5    75  10.8    0.0 --- 0.00    0.0 --- 15.2    14.9    14.9    13.4    1012.0  0.00    0.0 0   0.00    0   0.0 0.00    0.0 0.066   0.000   21.4    49  10.2    20.5    9.05    1.1829  0.00    702 1   100.0   30
01/01/16    2:30 a  14.4    15.2    14.0    79  10.8    0.0 --- 0.00    0.0 --- 14.4    14.2    14.2    12.8    1012.2  0.20    0.0 0   0.00    0   0.0 0.00    0.0 0.082   0.000   21.4    48  9.9 20.4    8.86    1.1834  0.00    703 1   100.0   30
01/01/16    3:00 a  15.1    15.1    14.1    76  10.9    0.0 --- 0.00    0.0 --- 15.1    14.8    14.8    13.4    1011.9  0.00    0.0 0   0.00    0   0.0 0.00    0.0 0.068   0.000   21.4    48  9.9 20.4    8.86    1.1830  0.00    700 1   100.0   30
01/01/16    3:30 a  14.9    15.2    14.9    73  10.1    0.0 --- 0.00    0.0 --- 14.9    14.6    14.6    13.2    1011.9  0.00    0.0 0   0.00    0   0.0 0.00    0.0 0.071   0.000   21.4    47  9.6 20.3    8.75    1.1833  0.00    702 1   100.0   30
01/01/16    4:00 a  15.2    15.3    14.9    68  9.4 0.0 --- 0.00    0.0 --- 15.2    14.8    14.8    13.3    1011.9  0.00    0.0 0   0.00    0   0.0 0.00    0.0 0.065   0.000   21.4    47  9.6 20.3    8.75    1.1833  0.00    700 1   100.0   30
01/01/16    4:30 a  14.9    15.2    14.6    72  9.9 0.0 --- 0.00    0.0 --- 14.9    14.6    14.6    13.1    1011.8  0.00    0.0 0   0.00    0   0.0 0.00    0.0 0.072   0.000   21.3    46  9.2 20.2    8.64    1.1838  0.00    703 1   100.0   30
01/01/16    5:00 a  14.1    15.1    14.0    76  9.9 0.0 --- 0.00    0.0 --- 14.1    13.8    13.8    12.3    1012.1  0.00    0.0 0   0.00    0   0.0 0.00    0.0 0.088   0.000   21.3    46  9.2 20.2    8.64    1.1842  0.00    702 1   100.0   30
```

and I want to import it into a Data Frame but with one column contating the date and the time in 24 hour display together:

```
Time
01/01/16 12:30
.....
01/01/16 13:30
```

Is there an easy way to do this ?

Thank you !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

For `dd/mm/yy` format:

```
def parse_dt(dt, tm, ap):
    return pd.to_datetime(dt + ' ' + tm + ap, dayfirst=True)
```

For `mm/dd/yy` format:

```
def parse_dt(dt, tm, ap):
    return pd.to_datetime(dt + ' ' + tm + ap)
```

Parse CSV:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\s+', skiprows=2, header=None,
                 parse_dates={'ts': [0,1,2] }, date_parser=parse_dt)
```

Comment: Thank you ! it's working ! But is there a way to keep the headers?

Comment: @RonMaor, you are welcome. It wasn't clear from your input data what date format you are using