# Pandas: losing data while sorting Data Frame by Hour Averages

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Dataframe (Time column is the index):

[image]

Which goes until 2016-11-4 11:30:00.

I'm trying to get the averages for every hour using:

```
df3 = df2.resample('H').agg(['mean','std'])
df3.columns = [' '.join(col) for col in df3.columns]
```

But in my result I get only until 2016-12-3:

[image]

What is the problem ?

Thank you !!

Comment: `2016-12-03` is `3 DEC 2016` and `2016-11-04` is `4 NOV 2016`, so it seems to be OK

Comment: But the second argument represents the day ! it's until 11 April 2016

Comment: no, it doesn't. What is the date format in your [original data set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36662422/pandas-importing-date-and-12-hour-time-together) - `dd/mm/yy` or `mm/dd/yy`?

Comment: mm/dd/yy is the original text file.